# Unit testing Kotlin's ConflatedBroadcastChannel behavior

Tags: kotlin, listener, channel, kotlin-coroutines, behaviorsubject

In the new project that I'm currently working on I have no RxJava dependency at all, because until now I didn't need that - coroutines solve threading problem pretty gracefully.

At this point I stumbled upon on a requirement to have a [`BehaviorSubject`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/channels.html)-alike behavior, where one can subscribe to a stream of data and receive the latest value upon subscription. As I've learned, [`Channel`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/channels.html)s provide very similar behavior in Kotlin, so I decided to give them a try.

From [this](https://proandroiddev.com/part-3-transmitting-streams-of-value-with-channels-70cf8dccf2b) article I've learned, that [`ConflatedBroadcastChannel`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-conflated-broadcast-channel/) is the type of channel that mimics `BehaviorSubject`, so I declared following:

```
class ChannelSender {

    val channel = ConflatedBroadcastChannel<String>()

    fun sendToChannel(someString: String) {
         GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { channel.send(someString) }
    }
}
```

For listening to the channel I do this:

```
    class ChannelListener(val channelSender: ChannelSender) {
        fun listenToChannel() {
            channelSender.channel.consumeEach { someString ->
                if (someString == "A") foo.perform() 
                else bar.perform()
            }
        }
    }
```

This works as expected, but at this point I'm having difficulties understanding how to unit test `ChannelListener`.

I've tried to find something related [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/test/guide), but none of `example-channel-**.kt` classes were helpful.

Any help, suggestion or correction related to my incorrect assumptions is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What about https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/test/channels (in particular https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/test/channels/ConflatedBroadcastChannelNotifyStressTest.kt)?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, a lot of code there, let me analyze it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, thanks for the help, it indeed lead me to correct direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [help of Alexey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56848248/unit-testing-kotlins-conflatedbroadcastchannel-behavior/56852145#comment100247655_56848248) I could manage to end up having following code, which answers the question:

```
class ChannelListenerTest {

  private val val channelSender: ChannelSender = mock()

  private val sut = ChannelListener(channelSender)
  private val broadcastChannel = ConflatedBroadcastChannel<String>()

  private val timeLimit = 1_000L
  private val endMarker = "end"

  @Test
  fun `some description here`() = runBlocking {
    whenever(channelSender.channel).thenReturn(broadcastChannel)

    val sender = launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
      broadcastChannel.offer("A")
      yield()
    }

    val receiver = launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
      while (isActive) {
        val i = waitForEvent()
        if (i == endMarker) break
        yield()
      }
    }

    try {
      withTimeout(timeLimit) {
        sut.listenToChannel()
        sender.join()
        broadcastChannel.offer(endMarker) // last event to signal receivers termination
        receiver.join()
      }
      verify(foo).perform()
    } catch (e: CancellationException) {
      println("Test timed out $e")
    }
  }

  private suspend fun waitForEvent(): String =
      with(broadcastChannel.openSubscription()) {
        val value = receive()
        cancel()
        value
      }

}
```